# Entity Framework: How can I assign permissions on new code first tables?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I think the question speaks for itself. I have a fairly typical case where I've created a new entity class on which I've specified the [Table] attribute. The Add-Migration command has generated the corresponding DbMigration.CreateTable, etc.

However, I would like to ensure that the table is create in SQL Server with the select permission assigned to group... let's call it ABCGRP.

Can this be done via attributes, the Fluent API or will I need to simply create a SQL script with a GRANT operation?

Comment: see https://romiller.com/2013/02/27/ef6-writing-your-own-code-first-migration-operations/

Comment: I ended up using the Sql command, but interesting article. Thanks!